# User first name is not displayed after registration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm building a React and Node.js app. In the frontend, when the user logs in, they are directed from the /login route to the root route and they are greeted with their first name, however, when the user registers, and is directed to the root route from the /register route, the first name is not displayed.

Login.js

```
const Login = ({history}) => {
    //Return jsx code
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('john.doe@gmail.com');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('test');

    const submitForm = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(login({email, password}, history))
        navigate("/")
    }
```

Register.js

```
const Register = ({ history }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [gender, setGender] = useState('male');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
    const submitForm = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()

        dispatch(register({ firstName, lastName, email, gender, password}, history))
        navigate("/")
    }
```

authServices.js

```
const AuthService = {

    login: (data) => {
        return API.post('/login' , data)
        .then(({data}) => {
            API.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${data.token}`;
            return data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Auth service err" ,err)
            throw err
        })
    },

    register: (data) => {
        return API.post('/register', data)
        .then(({ data }) => {
            API.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${data.token}`;
            return data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Auth service err" ,err)
            throw err
        })
    }
```

Chat.js

```
const Chat = () => {
    //Return jsx code

    const user = useSelector(state => state.authReducer.user)
    // console.log(user)

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>Chat screen</h1>
        <p>Welcome, {user.firstName}</p>
    </div>
    );
}
```

auth.js

```
export const login = (params, history) => dispatch => {
    return AuthService.login(params)
    .then(data => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: data})
        history.push("/")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

export const register = (params, history) => dispatch => {
    return AuthService.register(params)
    .then(data => {
        dispatch({type: REGISTER, payload: data})
        history.push('/')
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

auth.js

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

const {type, payload } = action

switch (type) {
    case LOGIN:
        return {
            ...state,
            user: payload,
            token: payload.token,
            isLoggedIn: true
        }

        case REGISTER:
        return {
            ...state,
            user: payload,
            token: payload.token,
            isLoggedIn: true
        }

        default: {
            return state
        }
}
```

}

index.js inside store folder

```
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    // import {thunk} from 'redux-thunk'
    import rootReducer from './reducers'

    // const store = configureStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: rootReducer,
        middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware()
      
      });

    export default store
```

root reducer code
index.js

```
                import { combineReducers } from "redux";
            import authReducer from "./auth";

            export default combineReducers({
                // auth: authReducer  This did not work either
                authReducer
            })
```

I've tried different methods of trying to solve this issue but none seem to work.
Why is the first name displayed for the login but not for the register?

Comment: Could you share `authReducer`? It seems to be the most interesting part of your issue investigation.

Comment: If you add `console.log(data)` for both `login` and `register` right before `return data` in AuthService, which fields `data` has in both cases?

Comment: Hi there, do consider reducing the amount of code we have to read through, and do check your `auth.js` as well, it seems to be awkwardly duplicated. All the best!

Comment: In the authServices file, I added a console log statement in the login and register methods. The login returns an object in the console containing the users information such as firstName, lastName, etc., whereas the register does not. " console.log("Auth Service login data:",data);" " console.log("Auth Service register data:",data);"

Answer (score 0):

You should also provide the store.js file to see how you setup your key but I'd suggest that you modify the `Chat.js` file because it seems as if you are accessing the wrong key in the store:

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
```

Comment: This returns "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')"

Comment: Can you also show your rootReducer file? And, when you console.log the user, what was the result?

Comment: I have added the file. And when i console log the user for "    const user = useSelector(state => state.authReducer.user)
" it returns an empty object, but "const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
" caused an error